# Regular Expression for finding font-style in html style

Tags: javascript

Any idea how to find and replace the HTML font-size  in style attribute?

```
eg.   <span style="font-size:12px">hello world</span>
```

I would like to remove all font-size using javascript.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH GOD NO NOT REGULAR EXPRESSIONS AAAAAAHHHHHH ;-) You should do this using the DOM manipulation methods of Javascript - that's what they're there for.

```
var theSpan = ...;
theSpan.style.removeProperty("font-size");
```

Here's [one reference](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0440__Style/Removeastylevaluebypropertyname.htm).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("span").each( function() {
     $(this).css("font-size", "");
});
```

You can loop through the desired elements using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a Javascript function to find all spans and replace their font size.

```
function changeFontSize(newSize) {
   var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
   for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
    {
      spans[i].style.fontSize=newSize ;
    }
}
```

The argument `newSize` is a string.  If you set it to "50px", all spans will have a 50px font size.  If you set it to "", it will have the same effect as removing the fontsize.